# Converting several 2D images into 3D model

Tags: 3d, visualization, graphic

I would like to try make software very similar to this - 123dapp.com/catch. I really would like to know the way how to achieve this in for example Visual Studio. If it is even possible. The reason I don`t want to use this software is because I would like to have a program that does all of this automatically. I want to code a program where I would just import several images and I would get a 3D model and than work with the model inside my program. Is this possible? If so, can anyone help me to get into this? Thank you

Reason I am writing this post here is because I don`t know where to start studying this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Structure from Motion (SFM) pipeline. Writing one yourself will take some time; its a complex system. The steps are

- Detect which points in the images show the same point of the scene (feature matching).
- Estimate the camera position of each image.
- Estimate scene geometry using multiview stereo (dense reconstruction).
- Turn your scene geometry into a triangle mesh.

There are tools that do all this like [VisualSFM](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ccwu/vsfm/) freely available. You put in images and get a 3D model out. Parts of VisualSFM are open source and the [Bundler](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~snavely/bundler/) project is another good resource. Still, it will require a bit of research if you want to piece together your own system.

If you want to take a look into the research behind it, ["Visual modeling with a hand-held camera"](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/pomarc/pubs/PollefeysIJCV04.pdf) by Pollefeys et al. is a good start.